# C program is not executing well in Code::Blocks 13.12

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// count lines in input
main() {
  int c, nl;
  nl = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n')
      ++nl;
  }
  printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

Whenever I build and run this program, it opens a console window and when I press `enter` it does not give me the newline count.

Comment: i dont think we can have char in int

Comment: Change `main()` to `int main(void)`.

Comment: Do you end the loop? you have to send `EOF` to end it. (Ctrl+D) or (Ctrl+Z on MS Windows).

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi; Yes. We can have and in this case it is a good idea to store `char` in `int` for `EOF`.

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi the opposite is not possible. You shouldn't cast `int` to `char` because `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` but it's ok the other way, for the same reason.

Comment: as Haccks told `main()` The C90 standard grudgingly tolerated this form, but the C99 and C11 standards don’t so use int `main(void)` instead

Comment: thnaks didn't know that we can do it by that way too , because never found use of ascii value in such case

Comment: It s  a program copied from the book c programming 2nd edition by dennis richie (founder of c)  and brian w kernighan ...but it s not ruunning in code blocks software...it compiles very well but does not gives the output i want ....as i told you guys .a console window appears when i start typing characters and enter key it has to give me the number of times i have pressed the enter key beacaue of \n condition but it does not give output.....i just type a character and it simply showing it in console window and when i press enter it shows a new line in console window...rather than counting it

Comment: I have changed main() to int main()  but doesn t work

Comment: getchar() actually returns an int and EOF is an int, so 'c' must be defined as int

Comment: '\n' is (effectively enter)  so to actually exit the loop a <ctrl-d> (generates EOF) needs to be entered at the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

To get the output you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (for DOS/Windows) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (for UNIX) to pass `EOF`.

---

**Side Note:** The signature of `main` as per defined by C standard is either of

```
int main(void)   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: I'm using '-std=c99'  The compiler also allows: 'int main()'  although I did not see that in the standards document.  I'm compiling with gcc under ubuntu 14.04 linux and gcc 4.8.2

Comment: @user3629249; I know. You will not find that signature in standard. Search in compilers doc.

Answer (score -1):

Put all the code that needed to be executed when certain condition is satisfied in a code block like:

```
if (c == '\n') {
   ++nl;
   printf("%d\n", nl);   
}
```

And define c as char instead of integer.

Comment: I don't think he wants to do that. He wants to print the number of lines at the end of the loop, so regardless of the ugly way he wrote his program, it's correct.

Comment: Despite the OP's indentation, your version doesn't look like it matches, what the OP's is trying to do. The lack of `{` / `}` (though confusing) in the OP's code seems to be quite intentional.